# BLE - Where can I find what data of individual GATT services can be advertised in "service data" in extended advertising packet?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I read a lot of Bluetooth specification documents (core, GAP, GATT, individual services, individual characteristics), but I can not find what data of individual GATT services (for example: heart rate service, blood pressure service, health termometer service, ...) can be advertised in "service data" (GAP data type value - 0x16) in extended advertising packet.

Core document says: ***The service specification defines how the characteristics are to be formatted in the service data** which follows the service UUID in the Service Data Advertising Data type payload.*
[BLUETOOTH CORE SPECIFICATION Version 5.3 | Vol 3, Part G page 1482]

Core supplement document says: *The Service Data data type consists of a service UUID with **the data associated with that service**.*
[Supplement to the Bluetooth Core Specification | CSS v10, Part A page 19]

But in specifications of services I read, is just nothing about advertising.

Only "half useful" thing I found is this example: https://github.com/NordicPlayground/nrf51-ble-app-temp/blob/master/main.c ,
where it seems only thing advertised from [Health Termometer Service] is [Temperature Measurement Value Field] of [Temperature Measurement Characteristic].
But how can be the value of temperature interpreted, when information if it is in °C or °F is in [Flag Field] which is not advertised?



So, I suppose there should be some other documentation about *service data* in *extended advertising package*, which I can not find.
So, the help I need from you guys is:
Where can I find what data of individual GATT services can be advertised in "service data" in extended advertising packet?

Answer (score 0):

The service specifications specify the format of the advertising data for "service data" fields. If you can't find any service data specification in a service specification document, then there is no valid service data and having any service data advertised for that service would be invalid.

I guess that old nrf sample code is invalid, because the health termometer service does not define any service data.

Comment: If so, this should be noted in the core specification. "The service specification defines how the characteristics are to be formatted in the service data" can be understood as: "Every service can be a part of Service Data, go and look for details", and people look for details, but there are no details, so people wonder why there are no details. People are frustrated because they expect something to be in these specifications. An example of a specification which mentions something about contents of Service Data is Battery Service Specification, specifically the Battery Level characteristic.